# Reduce Padding Around Text in WinForms Button

Tags: .net, winforms, button, fonts, paint

I have an application that is going to be used on a touch screen system, and it contains a number of buttons that are fairly large (~100px square).

Each button will have between 1 and 4 lines of text (typically one word per line).

Due to the large amount of padding in the button, I'm having to reduce the size of the text so that it becomes almost unreadable, however if I was able to reduce the internal padding so that the text would paint right up to the border, then I wouldn't have a problem.

I've attempted to reduce the padding of the control down to zero as follows, but it doesn't help.

```
this.Text = _label;
this.Font = new Font(this.Font.FontFamily, (float) _size);
this.Padding = new Padding(0);
```

An example of the problem is shown below:

[image: Button with broken text]

As you can see there is plenty of space for the word 'OVERVIEW' to fit on one line, but how can I achieve this without reducing the font size? I don't relish the thought of having to rewrite the control's text painting code.

Edit: I've noticed that increasing the padding to various values as high as 300, makes no difference to the internal padding of the control. Also for information, the button I'm using is a control I've inherited from the Windows.Forms.Button class, as I need to add a few properties, however I haven't interfered with any of the Button's own methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You also simply override the OnPaint() method of the Button control from which you're inheriting, and omit to call base.OnPaint(), and replace it with your own draw code.

```
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)
    {
        //omit base.OnPaint completely...

        //base.OnPaint(pevent); 

        using (Pen p = new Pen(BackColor))
        {
            pevent.Graphics.FillRectangle(p.Brush, ClientRectangle);
        }

        //add code here to draw borders...

        using (Pen p = new Pen(ForeColor))
        {
            pevent.Graphics.DrawString("Hello World!", Font, p.Brush, new PointF(0, 0));
        }
    }
```

Comment: That would be my preferred method, however it isn't that simple, as the existing paint event will deal with the wrapping and positioning of the text within the bounds, hence the reason why I'm not keen on going down this road, unless of course there is any easy method of achieving this?

Comment: Accepted, as Graphics.DrawString does make easy work of text wrapping and positioning. Works perfectly, many thanks.

Comment: Cool, simpler than my suggestion and it sounds like it works. +1

Comment: @Jodrell, did you delete your answer? I can't see it any more! Yes this works brilliantly, now I'm working on trying to dynamically size the font to the optimum size. New question being posted in 5.. 4.. :)

Comment: Bryan, do a call to pevent.Graphics.MeasureString(...) and compare the SizeF result with the ClientRectangle of the button. A few lines of math should sort you out to center the text easily. You can also then start applying auto-ellipse ;)

Answer (score 7):

You don't have to draw the whole button yourself.
Just leave Text property empty and assign your text to OwnerDrawText

```
public class NoPaddingButton : Button
{
    private string ownerDrawText;
    public string OwnerDrawText
    {
        get { return ownerDrawText; }
        set { ownerDrawText = value; Invalidate(); }
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ownerDrawText))
        {
            StringFormat stringFormat = new StringFormat();
            stringFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            stringFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;

            e.Graphics.DrawString(ownerDrawText, Font, new SolidBrush(ForeColor), ClientRectangle, stringFormat);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I have created a successful radio automation application back then in '98 using MFC.  First thing we did is that we created whole new set of GUI controls for it, since for example, pressing the button on the screen with the finger obscures it, and standard buttons aren't so fancy for it.

[image: fireplay image]

My advice would be not to go with deriving your button from standard WinForms button, but from the `Control` and do the drawing yourself.  If it is the simple button like one you presented, you won't have much to do, just DrawString, and if it is somewhat more complicated, you'll have complete control over it.

Comment: What a design, looks very cool! The link is not working anymore.

Answer (score 2):

@Bryan - both solutions proposed by @Henk Roux and @chiper are not perfect. First generate button without any visual attributes and second forces us to add new attribute like `OwnerDrawText`.

See my proposition below. I override `Text` property to be able to use its private part `_Text` and attach `String.Empty` just before `MyBase.OnPaint(e)` event. This makes that button is draw without text. Later on I reassign back old text to the private property and draw string myself. I add `Inflate` to `Rectangle` to make text nicer just touching border of button, not overlapping it. My proposition works with any `flatstyle`.

[Here is comparison of standard and no padding button in two flatstyles: standard and flat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKZGC.png)

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class ButtonNoPadding
    Inherits Button

    Private _textCurrent As String
    Private _Text As String

    <Category("Appearance")>
    Public Overrides Property Text() As String
        Get
            Return _Text
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            If value <> _Text Then
                _Text = value
                Invalidate()
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(e As PaintEventArgs)

        _textCurrent = Text
        _Text = String.Empty
        MyBase.OnPaint(e)
        _Text = _textCurrent

        Using brush = New SolidBrush(ForeColor)
            Using stringFormat = New StringFormat() With {.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center, .LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center}
                e.Graphics.DrawString(Text, Font, brush, Rectangle.Inflate(ClientRectangle, -2, -2), stringFormat)
            End Using
        End Using

    End Sub

End Class
```

C# version:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class ButtonNoPadding : Button
{

    private string _textCurrent;

    private string _Text;
    [Category("Appearance")]
    public override string Text {
        get { return _Text; }
        set {
            if (value != _Text) {
                _Text = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        _textCurrent = Text;
        _Text = string.Empty;
        base.OnPaint(e);
        _Text = _textCurrent;

        using (var brush = new SolidBrush(ForeColor)) {
            using (var stringFormat = new StringFormat {Alignment = StringAlignment.Center,LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center}) {
                e.Graphics.DrawString(Text, Font, brush, Rectangle.Inflate(ClientRectangle, -2, -2), stringFormat);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

On compatible WinForms controls you can also try setting the `UseCompatibleTextRendering` property to `true`. It uses the `Graphics` class instead of the default `TextRenderer` class for text rendering. While it worked for my specific application, your mileage may vary.

At least one con to this approach is the apparent font size seemed to change (reduced in my case).

Learn more here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.label.usecompatibletextrendering?view=netframework-4.8