# A button's text printing is quite wasteful. How can I make use of the wasted space?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, button

On my Windows form I added a button named Button1, containing the standard text Button1.

This button has some of the standard properties changed:

- **Font** = Arial, Standard, 9.75 (select 10)
- **FlatStyle** = Flat
- **FlatAppearance.BorderSize** = 0
- **Size** = 60; 60

It appears, that the available space is used very wastefully.

[image: Wasteful space usage]

Surely Button1 could be printed in a single line, probably even Button111. The Padding property was not touched and is 0; 0; 0; 0.

**The question:** Is it possible to use more of the available space (other than creating a dedicated user control)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reduce Padding Around Text in WinForms Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107108/reduce-padding-around-text-in-winforms-button)

Comment: @ChristopherKyleHorton Thanks, I see. Well, it's not VB.Net, so I struggle a bit there. It also seems the 3rd answer by yarecki concludes, that both other answers have shortcomings, but he presents an own answer. Only that this answer is even more cumbersome for me to grasp. I will see, if I can make sense out of it, though.

Comment: As a fellow VB.NET developer, I can relate to your comment regarding answers in C#. Unfortunately, the latter seems to get a lot more discussion online than the former, but they are both .NET languages and share a lot of concepts. After a while, I just had to teach myself how to translate the C# examples I find everywhere into the VB.NET equivalents that I need. I hope you don't run into too many difficulties.

Comment: @ChristopherKyleHorton, thanks. I managed to overlook a VB friendly version there. I applied the solution, and after modifying it a tad, it worked (see edited question). - What is best practice, to remove my querstion?

Comment: I had already flagged this question as a duplicate (my first comment was actually automatically inserted as a result of that action), but others will have to vote to actually close this. In the meantime, you could post your solution as an answer below, and if nothing happens in the next 48 hours then you could accept your own answer and mark this as resolved.

Comment: @ChristopherKyleHorton, will do so tomorrow, if the question does not seem to be on the best track to be closed. Thanks for your advice and the finding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to user [ChristopherKyleHorton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3775798/christopher-kyle-horton), who found a [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107108/reduce-padding-around-text-in-winforms-button) of this question (albeit marked with the general .Net keyword, triggering mostly C# answers), I came along a work by user [yarecki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5213964/yarecky).

I improved it a bit, and commented it extensively. If you also have the need for a truely flat button (no borders, text usage including all pixels), then put the following code in a new Class Library project and include a reference to it in your toolbox.

```
'In order to see the Text property in the appearance section of the properties 
'window, the Category attribute needs to be modified, which requires the 
'inclusion of the ComponentModel namespace.
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class FlatButton
Inherits Button

'============================================================================
'VARIABLES.
'============================================================================

'Property variables.
Private gsText As String

'============================================================================
'PROPERTIES.
'============================================================================

'Modifying the category attribute requires the import of the ComponentModel
'namespace.
<Category("Appearance")>
Public Overrides Property Text() As String
    Get
        Return gsText
    End Get
    Set(ByVal sValue As String)
        If sValue <> gsText Then    'If the new text differs from the old
            gsText = sValue         'one indeed, store it.
            Me.Invalidate()         'Invalidate causes a paint message to be 
        End If                      'sent to the control.
    End Set
End Property

'============================================================================
'EVENTS.
'============================================================================

'When the flat button control is being *displayed* for the first time, the
'HandleCreated event is fired. In it, the button's typical characteristics
'are set.
Private Sub FlatButton_HandleCreated(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
    Handles Me.HandleCreated

    FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat      'Make the button flat.
    FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0   'Display no borders at all.
End Sub

'Fires when the Text property is modified, enforced by the Invalidate
'method coded there.
Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(e As PaintEventArgs)
    Dim sSaveText As String         'Saves the current text.

    sSaveText = Me.Text             'Save the current text.
    gsText = String.Empty           'Blank the Text property.
    MyBase.OnPaint(e)               'Erase the client area.
    gsText = sSaveText              'Restore the Text property.

    '(Using has the effect to automatically dispose the used objects when 
    'done.)

    'Acquire a new SolidBrush resource with the ForeColor color.
    Using oBrush = New SolidBrush(ForeColor)

        'Acquire a new StringFormat resource centering the text.
        Using oStringFormat = New StringFormat() With
            {.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center,
            .LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center}

            'Draw the string contained in Text with the acquired brush in the
            'acquired string format, in the button's client rectangle, which 
            'is enlarged by 3 pixels in each direction. The original client
            'rectangle has a padding of 3 pixels to allow for a 2 pixels wide
            'border (3D), and a 1-pixel margin between the border and the 
            'actual text.
            e.Graphics.DrawString(Me.Text, Me.Font, oBrush,
                Rectangle.Inflate(ClientRectangle, 3, 3), oStringFormat)
        End Using                   'Dispose the StringFormat object.
    End Using                       'Dispose the oBrush object
End Sub

End Class
```

Using this control does reduce the padding around the text, compare before (left) and after (right):

[image]

Hope this helps someone as well.